# scrollTop is acting crasy in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

i am creating a small web site and what i wanted was to when i resize the windows size the scroll bar should go upto the top so i wrote a small function and called it on `<body onresize="resize()">` this is my function

```
 function resize(){
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
      }, 600);
            return false;
        }
```

now what i wanted is ok but now i can't scroll down some times.the scroll bar is going to up again and again why is that

Comment: Sounds like body's `onresize` is being called a lot. Maybe things are being inserted into the body dynamically or something? I would bind the resize function to the `window` resizing, not the `body`.

Comment: no still the same thing is happening  and i am not adding anything dynamically

Comment: Try this: remove `onresize="resize()"` from your body element, and in your javascript, instead of saying `function resize(){...}` say `window.onresize = function(){...};`

Comment: well i tried that too but still the same thing is hapaning

Comment: Can you post some of your html or the rest of your javascript that might be related? The `resize()` function you have seems to be okay, it's just a matter of it being triggered too often.

Comment: http://justpaste.it/oxsp this is my rest of the  java script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found the answer so i have to wait until the re sizing is finished to move the scroll bar up

the answer is

```js
var resizeId;
$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeId);
  resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});


function doneResizing() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
  <h1>asd</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to reply in a comment, but my reputation isn't high enough yet. I would advise against an auto scroll to top on resize. This is bad user experience. You should provide an option to scroll to top. An example would be a button that appears when the window resizes or a user scrolls down. If a user clicks that button, it would scroll them to the top of the window.

Comment: well yeah i could add a button but i want to do this without a button.any idea how to do this without one??.

Comment: If you really wanted to resize without giving the user an option, which I would advise against...You can check if the user is scrolling on your resize event. If the user is not scrolling, you scroll to the top. If they are, do not. I can provide an example if you need one.

Comment: can you pleace tell me how to detect if the user is scrolling or not

Comment: well i found it and it is working thnak you so much for the help @digitalbs

Comment: You can check to see if the width is the same as the resized width. If it isn't, resize.
http://plnkr.co/edit/7yLz4D?p=preview